# How do I strip 'public_html' and parameters from URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have come across a problem, where my whole web-project is under a subdirectory of a subdirectory in my web server, therefore the 'public_html' folder in there does not fall off from the URL.

Is there a way to do this strip via **.htaccess** in a clean way?

---

**Here is an example of my URL structure:**

```
http://myurl.domain.com/portfolio/projects/MyProject/public_html/?page=home
```

---

I would also like to perform some cleaning to my URL by stripping off the `?page=` parameters, but I'm running a PHP config with an array which sets the `<title>` of the current page by identifying the current parameter in use with `$_GET`.

Second question is; can I strip those parameters off or will that break my title-setup and if I can and it will not break anything, how am I supposed to do it?

---

Thanks in advance, I'm a total newbie when it comes to .htaccess and any help and advice granted I will hoard to my knowledge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your root htaccess file ,try adding this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /portfolio/projects/MyProject/public_html/\?page=([^\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /portfolio/projects/MyProject/%1? [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?portfolio/projects/MyProject/([^/]+)/?$ /portfolio/projects/MyProject/public_html/?page=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

This will redirect "/portfolio/projects/MyProject/public_html/?page=pagename" **to** "/portfolio/projects/MyProject/pagename" stripping out the **public_html** folder and querystrings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this seems to create some sort of a problem here, for my URL is now the following: `http://myurl.domain.com/portfolio/projects/MyProject/?portfolio/projects/`

Any idea on what could be wrong? I tried to change the .htaccess file location to the root of my 'portfolio' -folder, but this did not make a change. Firsthand try was that the .htaccess file was located in the 'MyProject' folder. **I can not use the root folder of the web server, therefore I have to put it under the project folder or my portfolio, if that matters.**

Comment: Got it figured out!
And thanks for Mikko in guidance for RewriteBase, this helped.